# Get better random value with Groovy

Tags: list, random, groovy

I use following `Groovy` code to select random elements from a list.

```
Random rnd = new Random()
log.info("Random element:" + list[rnd.nextInt(list.size)])
```

I get previous or next element as a "random" value in most cases.

Comment: This code should work correctly. Show your list please.

Comment: The code is fine in its own right, but if it's not 'random enough', then seed it with a better/moving value.  I'd typically seed it with some like current seconds and milliseconds as a four digit integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy method to get a random element from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033940/groovy-method-to-get-a-random-element-from-a-list)

Comment: @ChrisAdams : Could you please show example with seed usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with seeding.

In the past, I found that when generating random numbers, they were not quite 'random enough' and I have tried a few different way to make it more random.

E.g.

```
Date date = new Date();
def now = date.getTime();
log.info(now);  // This value is the number of millis since January 1, 1970

Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.setSeed(now); // Seed the Random with the millis value

def play = randomValue.nextInt(10);  // Value in brackets is the max number of interest
log.info(play);
```

When not working in ranges and just need a x-digit random value, I have done something like...

```
randomValue = new Random();
val1 = randomValue.nextInt(10);
val2 = randomValue.nextInt(10);
val3 = randomValue.nextInt(10);
val4 = randomValue.nextInt(10);
val5 = randomValue.nextInt(10);

orderRef = val1.toString() + val2.toString() + val3.toString()+ val4.toString()+ val5.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def <T> T getRandomElement(List<T> list) {
    if (list) {
        Collections.shuffle(list)
        list.first()
    }
}
```

Be aware that `Collections.shuffle` mutates the list. This might matter if there are references to the list elsewhere.